# Does using custom data attributes produce browser compatibility issues?

Tags: html, custom-attributes, custom-data-attribute

I have to choose between custom data tags or ids. I would like to choose custom data tags, but I want to be sure that they do not cause browser compatibility issues for the most widely used browsers today.

I'm using jQuery 1.6 and my particular scenario involves a situation where I need to reference a commentId for several actions.

```
<div data-comment-id="comment-1" id="comment-1">
   <a class="foo"></a>
</div>
```

It's easier to extract data tags in jQueryin: `$('foo').data('commentId');`

Extract a substring from the id seems a bit complicated and could break for one reason or another: `<a id="comment-1"`

Are there any sweeping merits or fatal flaws for either approach?

Comment: Custom data attributes don't validate under XHTML 1 or HTML 4, although that's nothing to do with browser compatibility - I believe they (like much of HTML5) were designed to work without causing issues in older browsers (i.e. IE).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974139/what-happens-if-you-use-custom-attribute-in-a-html-tag?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would advise in favor of data attributes for the following reasons:

- ids need to be unique document-wide. Thus they are limited in the semantics they can carry
- you can have multiple data-attributes per element

and probably less relevant in your case:

- changing ids might break idrefs

However, I'm not sure whether I understand your specs completely as extracting the element id in jQuery is as trivial as getting the data attribute: `$('.foo').attr('id');`.

You might be interested in [Caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/), a browser compatibility site for web technologies.

If XHTML is an issue to you, you might also be interested in how to use custom data attributes in XHTML: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189036/custom-data-in-xhtml-1-0-strict) for a discussion on SO and [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1453-Using-jQuery-With-Custom-XHTML-Attributes-And-Namespaces-To-Store-Data.htm) for an XHTML-compatible approach using namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

[this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6/2413263#2413263) says data attibutes work on IE6.